# How to add the text at the particular position in custom adapter in android

Tags: android, listview, maps, adapter

[image]I am creating android app that populates the list of GPS co-ordinates which was entered by the user using custom adapter like this

```
SELECTION         LAT        LONG         DISTANCE
-------------------------------------------------
  checkbox1    123.4546     456.48751      Text
  checkbox2    123.4546     456.48751      Text
  checkbox3    123.4546     456.48751      Text
  checkbox4    123.4546     456.48751      Text
```

If user selects the check-box 1 then i have to find the distance from check-box 1 lat long to check-box 2,check-box 3,check-box-4 lat long .Here i need to display the result text in the field of `Text` their respective position but here i am getting the result only at the last position can anyone tell me how to achieve it FYI:[![enter image description here][2]][2]
This sc will explain you in detail.
If i check the one value it was updating the result only at the last value but i need to update and display the result for the whole data
This is my code

```
check_locations.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                latitude_string = location.getLatitude();
                longitude_string = location.getLongitude();
                baseLat_double = Double.parseDouble(latitude_string);
                baseLong_double = Double.parseDouble(longitude_string);
                location_a = new Location("Base position");
                location_a.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(latitude_string));
                location_a.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(longitude_string));
                location_b = new Location("End position");
                for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                    finalLat_double = Double.parseDouble(objects.get(i).getLatitude());
                    finalLong_double = Double.parseDouble(objects.get(i).getLongitude());
                    location_b.setLatitude(finalLat_double);
                    location_b.setLongitude(finalLong_double);
                    distance = location_a.distanceTo(location_b);
                    distance = distance * 1.609344;
                    objects.get(i).setDistance(String.valueOf(distance));
                    }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                distance_text.setText(location.getDistance());

            }
        }
    });


    return locations_row;
}
```

Comment: At first study some thing about how to make an Adapter Class then do code.

Comment: I don't have much time bro for reading that doc.can you help me with this question @Nigam Patro

Comment: Inside `Locations_modle` add a variable for distance. And whenever the user checks checkbox update that variable in the list.

Comment: Yes,I did it but i am getting blank values @Nigam Patro

Comment: I updated the `getView()` method of your code. Please go through the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `getView()` methods something like this

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    final View locations_row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_adapter_list_details, null);
    final Locations_modle location = (Locations_modle) objects.get(position);
    TextView text_cust_name = (TextView) locations_row.findViewById(R.id.txt_cust_name_heading);
    TextView latitude = (TextView) locations_row.findViewById(R.id.txt_latitude);
    latitude.setText(location.getLatitude());
    TextView longitude = (TextView) locations_row.findViewById(R.id.txt_longitude);
    TextView distance_text = (TextView) locations_row.findViewById(R.id.txt_distance);
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(location.getDistance()))
        distance_text.setText("DISTANCE");
    longitude.setText(location.getLongitude());
    text_cust_name.setText(location.getLocationName());
    CheckBox check_locations = (CheckBox) locations_row.findViewById(R.id.check_locations);
    check_locations.setTag(position);

    if (position == selectedPostion) {
        check_locations.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        check_locations.setChecked(false);
    }
    check_locations.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                selectedPostion = (int) buttonView.getTag();

                latitude_string = objects.get(selectedPostion).getLatitude();
                longitude_string = objects.get(selectedPostion).getLongitude();

                baseLat_double = Double.parseDouble(latitude_string);
                baseLong_double = Double.parseDouble(longitude_string);

                location_a = new Location("Base position");
                location_a.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(latitude_string));
                location_a.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(longitude_string));

                location_b = new Location("End position");


                for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                    finalLat_double = Double.parseDouble(objects.get(i).getLatitude());
                    finalLong_double = Double.parseDouble(objects.get(i).getLongitude());
                    location_b.setLatitude(finalLat_double);
                    location_b.setLongitude(finalLong_double);
                    distance = location_a.distanceTo(location_b);
                    distance = distance * 1.609344;
                    objects.get(i).setDistance(distance);
                }
                Locations_Adapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

    return locations_row;
}
```

Comment: Mean for what, you are getting empty values?

Comment: Modify `objects.get(i).setDistance(distance);` this part of code inside for loop to this `objects.get(i).setDistance(String.valueOf(distance));`

Comment: Sorry for late i'll check it

Comment: If i write notifyOndatasetchanged it is blocking me from checking checkboxes

Comment: I edited my code and screen shot in the question have a look at this

Comment: Your code was working fine but when i am checking the checkbox it was not showing its checked state.Can you help me with that@Nigam Patro

Comment: Put this part of code

`if (position == selectedPostion) {
        check_locations.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        check_locations.setChecked(false);
    }` 

after `check_locations.setOnCheckedChangeListener()`.

Comment: No use bro i had written after oncheckedchange listener still not checking the checkboxes and what is selected position here@ Nigam Patro

Comment: Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the main layout of your row xml file. and check.

Comment: Still no use bro @Nigam Patro

Comment: What is the selected postion here bro

Comment: selectedposition is something the row which you have selected.

Comment: How can i get that inside on checked change listener @Nigam Patro

Comment: Ok bro now i got you every thing was working fine..thanks for answering patiently

Comment: Can you just like my answer?

Comment: Oh ! i forgot and thanks thanks for the help for up vote i need reputation of 15 sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

You inflated `locations_row` as a general view. This will create a new item every time. You need to reuse the existing items. I mean:

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_adapter_list_details, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

You didn't even use any of the `View convertView` or `final ViewGroup parent`
So, start from searching about **ViewHolder pattern for listview adapter**.

Comment: You will find a lot more useful sample codes by googling that bold text.

Comment: Ok bro i'll do it later but i dont have enough time now@JameNickel

Answer (score 0):

Check your xml layout that your row id is unique and you are using correctly distance_text Textview object. Maybe need to refresh the object in the for loop?

For me this code of yours is little hard to read but where do you use your ViewGroup parent and View convertView? From

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
```

For my quick overview you are only getting 1 instance of your `(TextView) locations_row.findViewById(R.id.txt_distance);` and that is the last position on your view. Make sure it get's refreshed as you want.